# How to get event when i open notification panel like device lock or unlock on iOS device in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-foundation

[image]

Below image is the notification panel.
I have used corefoundation framework to get events when we open notification panel, device unlock or unlock and blank screen state. I was getting all the events except when I drag notification panel.How to get events for notification panel.

Below code I have used to get events

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), nil, {
    (center, observer, name, object, userInfo) -> Void in
        let lockState = name
        print("lock state : \(String(describing: lockState))")
        print("DEVICE STATE CHANGED")

        if  AppConstants.sharedInstance.isDeviceLocked == true {
            print("DEVICE IS LOCKED")
        }
        else {
            print("DEVICE IS UNLOCKED")
            AppConstants.sharedInstance.isDeviceLocked = false
        }
    }, "com.apple.springboard.lockstate" as CFString, nil, CFNotificationSuspensionBehavior.deliverImmediately)
```